# Время и обновление в java

Tags: java

Я начинающий в java. Не могли бы вы сказать, как отмерять время (например, в секундах) и как заново запустить программу или вернуться в определённую её точку (без функций).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Выдать количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1970 года. В начале программы сохраняешь значение, а в конце снова вызываешь этот метод и сверяешься с первым значением. Результат в миллисекундах. На тысячу сам поделишь.

Класс Runtime и его метод `exec()` выполняют программу. Можешь в конце кода своей проги `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program.exe");`

А прыгать по точкам без функций - это бред какой-то. Почитай лучше книжки по яве и измени свою философию, чтобы отказаться от потребности "скакать по точкам".